# Regex find all words that begins with a vowel within a string

Tags: regex

How would the Regex be if I want to find all words that start with a vowel within a string? For example, 'We had apple, Oranges and pears for snacks.'

Shouldn't it be `/^[aeiouAEIOU]/`?
But it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? What does your code look like? Do you split the string first and then test each item with the regex? If you do, then split with `/\W+/` regex and your vowel regex will work, too. Else, to grab words starting with vowels without splitting first, use the solution from Pranav's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of [start anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) otherwise, only check the first character from the entire string and use `\w*` for remaining word character. Although use `i` flag for ignoring the case, depends on your programming language.

```
/\b[aeiou]\w*/ig
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^[aeiouAEIOU]\w+/`

searches for the beginning of the word and finishes with a word character expression. Should capture all words starting with vowels.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are in need of is

```
/\b[aeiouAEIOU]/g
```

You just have to begin with word boundary. Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([aeiou]).+\1$
```

it should work for:

abc
abcea -> True
aba -> True
aaabbae
baab -True
abca ->True
eaabe ->True
losso
olkao ->True